# How to execute a php file from a bash file?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, php

My goal is to make a script that I can execute through a cron job.

The script needs to find several killstat.php files in multiple directories and execute them.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
NAMETOFIND=$(find /home/ -name "killstat.php")
for i in $NAMETOFIND; do /usr/bin/php -f $i;
done
```

killstat.php should be executed to reset my statistics. But it seems the php file is not executed. When I change the -f switch to -l (syntax error checking) the script executes fine!

Executing `php killstat.php` from the CLI also works fine and resets the statistics.
I'm running as root and also killstat.php and my script are owned by root.
The script is chmod to 4755

### Solution provided by Hastur with tiny alteration.

I place this script in /etc/cron.monthly to reset my statistics.

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home -name "killstat.php"  | while read i
do
  Cdir=$(dirname "$i")
  Cname=$(basename "$i")     # This line can be avoided..
  cd "$Cdir"
  /usr/bin/php -f "$Cname";  # ...if here you use killstat.php [1]
  cd -
done
```

Comment: the paths in front of killstat.php are missing

Comment: I think the path is included to $i. I've made a simular script to convert php files from dos to unix which is using the same logic and that works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have problems when you have spaces in the `path` of the found files.
Try with a `while read  do ... done` loop like:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/ -name "killstat.php"  | while read i
do 
  /usr/bin/php -f "$i";
done
```

Note the double quotes **"** in `/usr/bin/php -f "$i";`

---

In case your script needs to run from *his place*

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/ -name "killstat.php"  | while read i
do 
  Cdir=$(dirname "$i")
  Cname=$(basename "$i")     # This line can be avoided...
  cd "$Cdir"
  /usr/bin/php -f "$Cname";  # ...if here you use killstat.php [1]
  cd -
done
```

Note again the double quote for `$i` just in case you have spaces in the string of directory.
The double are not really needed for `$Cname` since you know that, in this case, is `killstat.php`.
[1] You can put directly `killstat.php` instead of `$Cname` and avoid to write all the lines with Cname in the script.

Comment: Your script and my script will find the wanted file perfectly, but it just don't want to parse/execute the php file.

Comment: I suspect I need to set a permission to permit a bash script to parse/execute a php file. Replacing php -f with php -l shows that the files are found and checkt, [code]No syntax errors detected in /home/aaa/var/killstat.php
No syntax errors detected in /home/bbb/bbclone/var/killstat.php
No syntax errors detected in /home/ccc/var/killstat.php
[/code]

Comment: 1. If you have a directory named e.g. `Directory with spaces in the name` without double quote you will have an error.  2. It is possible that `killstat.php` needs, for some reasons, to be executed from the location where it is: in this case you have to change directory before execute it.

Comment: At first no success. After a tiny modification, find . -name to find /home -name it works! Will test the script now when executed as a cron job. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also as a cronjob the script works fine! Problem resolved! ;)

Comment: Nice to listen :)  The key was when I understand you said that `the -f switch to -l (syntax error checking) works fine`. It means that it finds the files `.php` and the file was correctly written... on the other side was able to produce correct results so it have to be a problem of path. You're welcome. ps> Did you need to search in the home for all users? It can be long...and dangerous (exploit)...

Comment: Well the script finishes within a second and find and execute 12 killstat.php files in the home directory. If you have security advise to prevent exploits I'm happy to hear them. But I'm the only user/owner of the VPS.

Comment: That's better. Imagine only if another user of your machine knows that there's a script (maybe a root one) that run and execute the code inside each file with a specific name... It can write something like `echo "Meow!" >/bin/cat` :-D inside a somewhere hidden file with that name...